# read a text file line by line

Tags: file, text, binaryreader, binarywriter

I need to read data from a text file line by line. Each line contains either a string or an integer. I want to use StreamReader to read line by line from the text file and StreamWriter to write it to a binary file. The "write to binary file" part will be easy. The "read from text file line by line" part is the part I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

It's all built into StreamReader:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(myFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // line is the text line
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions, but I get an error message "Illegal characters in path." It's just plain text that I'm reading and writing. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: That message means there's something wrong with your filename. Try debugging and take a look at the filename that you're using, you'll probably find a wayward slash or some other invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can do something like this.

```
string loc = "idk/where/ever";
using(var sr = new StreamReader(loc))
  using(var sw = new StreamWriter(loc+".tmp"))
    {
     string line; 
        while((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
           {
              sw.WriteLine(line);
                //edit it however you want
           }
     }
File.Delete(loc);
File.Move(loc+".tmp",loc);
```