# How do I read a text file line-by-line the "Pythonic" way

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I realize this is a common and simple question that has been asked before.  I was able to complete my project using a pseudo C method from the following post by **dawg**.  I used a 'while True' and tested for a blank line.
[read a text file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498495/read-a-text-file-line-by-line).

The IDE warns the local variable *line* is not used.  Changing variable *s* to *line* had not effect on the output.
But the Pytonic way suggested by **dawg** seemed to skip lines.  I have taken out all the processing I performed in the method (text to int, putting data into a list of tuples, and sorting it) and I rewrote the text file for this post. Similar results.

I also did try *sys.stdin* suggestion but do not have those results saved.

Obviously, I am a beginner with Python3.5.

```
# iofile_test3.py

with open('test_read_file.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    # read a line from file
    s = f.readline()
    print(s)


#test_read_file,txt
First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth and last line
```

---

```
######output#####
.Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06)
```

`>>>

```
Second line

Fourth and last line


>>>
```

I am using Pycharm 17.3 Community version but also tried this code with Idle with the same output.  Lines 1 and 3 seem to be skipped.   My OS is Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are skipped because you're throwing them away without printing them.  The usual way would be to not ignore them:

```
with open('test_read_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Okay.  So the for line reads once and the readline reads again.